# How do you alloc/dealloc unsafe pointers in Swift?

Tags: swift

With Beta 4, I had this code that worked fine:

```
var red, green, blue, alpha: UnsafePointer<CGFloat>
red = UnsafePointer<CGFloat>.alloc(1)
green = UnsafePointer<CGFloat>.alloc(1)
blue = UnsafePointer<CGFloat>.alloc(1)
alpha = UnsafePointer<CGFloat>.alloc(1)
myColor.getRed(red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red.memory, green.memory, blue.memory, 1)

red.dealloc(1)
green.dealloc(1)
blue.dealloc(1)
alpha.dealloc(1)
```

Now with Beta5, I get the error "'UnsafePointer.Type' does not have a member named 'alloc'".

All I'm trying to do is set the stroke color of the CGContext based on a UIColor.  How am I supposed to do this now?  The "withUnsafePointers" function is a bit of a joke - it's giving strange errors, and it only takes a maximum of three unsafe pointers, whereas I'm trying to use four in this case.

Comment: try `var red, green, blue, alpha: CGFloat;CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, &red, &green, &blue, 1)`

Comment: `UnsafePointer` is renamed to `UnsafeMutablePointer`. but you really need to avoid using them.

Comment: The whole Swift language is designed so that you don't have to fall back to using (unsafe) pointers. The main goal of Swift is to be a safe, reliable language.

Comment: @Byran Chen - Thank you, you have the correct answer.  To Bryan Chen and Oscar Swanros, I would love, love, love to stop using unsafe pointers, but the problem is that I am forced to.  Can you show me any way to set the CGContext stroke color based on a UIColor without using unsafe pointers?  I would be ecstatic if you could.

Comment: @user1021430 - How about this?

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100));
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    let color = UIColor.redColor();
    var components: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0];
    color.getRed(&components[0], green:&components[1], blue:&components[2], alpha:&components[3]);
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, components)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This works, Swift is smart enough to know what to do with the `&` operator:

```
let color = UIColor.purpleColor()
var r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, a:CGFloat = 0
color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(c, r, g, b, a)
```

If you really want to do the alloc yourself, use your favorite flavor and construct the pointer like this:

```
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>(calloc(1, UInt(sizeof(CGFloat))))
// later don't forget to free(p)
```

Comment: Amazing!!!  So I guess that putting "&" before arguments automatically converts them from Swift CGFloat to UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?  I wish that this was documented somewhere by Apple.  Because none of the documentation indicates anything close to this.  Also, one thing - Swift is too dumb to compile the line "var r, g, b, a: CGFloat = 0.0".  It gives the error "Type annotation missing in pattern".  So the variables must be declared each on their own line.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer (you could also do something like `var components: [CGFloat] = [0,0,0,0]` and reference the array elements instead.) This stuff is covered in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) under _Interacting With C APIs_.

Comment: Thanks.  OK, I see it in the reference now.  Wonder if I just totally missed that or if the reference was updated since I read it...

Answer (score 9):

`UnsafePointer<T>` no longer has a member `.alloc`.  Use `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc` instead.  e.g. the following `blankof()` works as a universal initializer.

```
func blankof<T>(type:T.Type) -> T {
    var ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<T>.alloc(sizeof(T))
    var val = ptr.memory
    ptr.destroy()
    return val
}

var red   = blankof(CGFloat)
var green = blankof(CGFloat)
var blue  = blankof(CGFloat)
var alpha = blankof(CGFloat)
color.getRed(&red, green:&green, blue:&blue, alpha:&alpha)
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, red, green, blue, 1)
// no need to dealloc because they are all structs, not pointers
```

Answer (score 4):

To answer your question about setting the stroke color from a `UIColor`, this will work:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myUIColor.CGColor);
```

I do this a lot in my C++-based Quartz 2D code.

Answer (score 1):

As of Beta 5 you can just pass your variables prefixed with &.
Just make sure to initialise them

More info on https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6

To use single variables, you can just set them to a zero value

```
var r: CGFloat = 0, g: CGFloat = 0, b: CGFloat = 0, a: CGFloat = 0
color.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)
```

To use C arrays, you just create a normal array with the indices you expect

```
var points:[NSPoint] = [NSPoint(), NSPoint(), NSPoint()] //notice how we set empty NSPoints
self.elementAtIndex(index, associatedPoints: &points)
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(path, nil, points[0].x, points[0].y, points[1].x, points[1].y, points[2].x, points[2].y)
```